# Tile map creation, problem with position of tiles

Tags: unity, tilemap

I am trying to create a basic tile map script to learn Unity and I am unable to understand why my tiles are spaced far apart and I can't seem to control their spacing.

Moreover, there seems to be a difference between tile map size and Unity sizes, how do I convert tile map size to Unity size?

My understanding of tile maps are limited but here is what I want to do. I want to be able to set tile size, amount of tiles displayed and the spacing between each tiles.

Image: http://puu.sh/in6XW/416f8971bc.png

```
 public static int TILE_WIDTH = 32;
 public static int TILE_HEIGHT = 32;

 public float tileSize = 0.1f;
 private Transform[,] tiles;

 void Start () {
     var w = 18; // width
     var h = 15;  // height
     tilePrefab.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
     tiles = new Transform[w,h];

     for (int y = 0; y < h; y++)
     { 
         for (int x = 0; x < w; x++)
         {
             Transform tile = Instantiate(tilePrefab, new Vector3(x* tileSize,y * tileSize,0),Quaternion.identity)as Transform;
             tile.parent = transform;
             tiles[x,y] = tile;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure whatever tile prefab you are using is scaled correctly.
I recommend using an object which is exactly one unity unit wide

Comment: I don't understand the tile engine's tilesize variable, am I supposed to get it right through trial and error?

Comment: It looks like its there in order to scale the whole tilemap down

Comment: Yet you are not scaling the prefab

Comment: Also line 3 in your start method is redundant

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but it looks like your "pixel to units" value is different, try setting it to your tile size, its very easy to handle it that way and if you do so, set the TILE_WIDTH and TILE_HEIGHT to 1